# How come my priority queue with my self-defined comparator is not giving the right order?

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

I have a priority queue that stores object of class `Process`. Each process has an attribute of `burst_time`.

I implemented the priority queue as below:

```
PriorityQueue<Process> srt = new PriorityQueue<Process>(42, new Comparator<Process>() {
            public int compare(Process o1, Process o2) {
                    if (o1.get_burstTime() < o2.get_burstTime()) return -1;
                    else if(o1.get_burstTime() > o2.get_burstTime()) return 1;
                    else return 0;
                };
});
```

However, as I read in 4 processes as below:

```
Process 1, burst_time 168
Process 2, burst_time 385
Process 4, burst_time 97
Process 3, burst_time 1770
```

It should be stored in priority queue as [4,1,2,3]. However no matter how I change the comparator it always shows in my code as [4,2,1,3].

Any idea what might have gone wrong?

Comment: This is a `java.util.PriorityQueue`? Can you show the code how you inspect the contents of the queue?

Comment: Read the javadoc of PriorityQueue.iterator().

Comment: Either use poll() to retrieve/remove them in order or else sort the PQ and then iterate:

        Arrays.sort(srt.toArray());